# How to solve the mount error in wsl?

Tags: 20.04, mount

mount: tmp-loop: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Ubuntu-20.04 WSL2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to give the whole story leading to this error. Although a similar question is asked at superuser.com https://superuser.com/questions/1518165/mounting-as-loop-device-fails-with-wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock

Wish you the best

Comment: This post doesn't help: sudo kpartx -av disk_images/mikeos.flp
device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop2p1  failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop2p1
device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop2p2  failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop2p2
device-mapper: reload ioctl on loop2p3  failed: Invalid argument
create/reload failed on loop2p3

Comment: Your file is a .flp file as seen in the comment.  First, create a file of the right size to be your "floppy":
`dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy bs=1k count=1440`
Now you have to "format" your "floppy", and we'll make it FAT32 (vfat):
`mkdosfs -F 32 floppy`
Now make a mountpoint for your "floppy"
`mkdir floppydisk`
Now mount your "floppy"
`mount -t vfat -o loop,defaults floppy floppydisk` . As taken from https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/mounting-a-flp-file-creating-an-flp-file-for-use-in-freedos-in-vmwear-550956/

Comment: Thank you mount works, but how to do boot.bin is bootable, not /dev/zero?

Comment: How make boot.bin bootable in floppy?

Comment: @MarioNikolaidis link-only answers are discouraged - please [edit] your answer to include the specific instructions from your [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1342425/how-to-solve-the-mount-error-in-wsl#comment2293615_1342427) so it doesn't get lost